# Copying HTML content of an object into a variable

Tags: jquery, html, object, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am making a drag and drop interface on a website with three draggables and four droppables. I want the content of each draggable to be displayed inside whichever droppable it is placed in to.

As you can see I'm trying to create a variable named `dropped1` from the droppable, but I am a jQuery newbie, and lost.

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div id="snaptarget1" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>Div 1</p> Correct Answer is 1
  </div>
  <div id="snaptarget2" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>Div 2</p> Correct Answer is 2
  </div>
  <div id="snaptarget3" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>Div 3</p> Correct Answer is 3
  </div>
  <br clear="both" />

  <div id="draggable1" class="draggable1 ui-widget-content">
    <p>Answer 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="draggable2" class="draggable1 ui-widget-content">
    <p>Answer 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="draggable3" class="draggable1 ui-widget-content">
    <p>Answer 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$("#snaptarget1").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var dropped1 = ui.prop('innerHTML');
    $('#drag1results').css('background-color', 'yellow')
    $(this)
      .droppable('disable')
      .removeClass("ui-widget-header")
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
      .find("p")
      .html("Dropped with " + dropped1 + "!")
    ui.draggable("option", "disabled", true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ui.draggable.text()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) is probably what you're looking for:

(Note: I left most of the rest of your code as is, just added `droppable`/`draggable` classes, though I'd ideally recommend querying on `data-` attributes in general):

```js
$('.draggable').draggable({revert: 'valid'});

$('.droppable').droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {  
    var dropped1 = ui.draggable.text().trim();
    $('#drag1results').css('background-color', 'yellow');
    
    $(this)
      .droppable('disable')
      .removeClass("ui-widget-header")
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
      .find("p")
      .html("Dropped with " + dropped1 + "!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<div class="demo">
  <div id="snaptarget1" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
    <p>Div 1</p> Correct Answer is 1
  </div>
  <div id="snaptarget2" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
    <p>Div 2</p> Correct Answer is 2
  </div>
  <div id="snaptarget3" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
    <p>Div 3</p> Correct Answer is 3
  </div>
  <br clear="both" />

  <div id="draggable1" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p>Answer 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="draggable2" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p>Answer 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="draggable3" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p>Answer 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time.

So when you say querying on data. Is the the same as “data-div” tags?

The sample of code I’m posting is a stripped down version where I had data-div tags already set up but wasn’t sure if this would work?

What would be the way of displaying the content of this if so?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you meant to post this as an answer? Are you the same person as the OP? You should post it as a comment to my answer instead.